# Traveled to Oman from Malaysia. Passport or visa was not stamped

Tags: visa, passport, oman

I'm asking for a friend. She travelled to Oman from Malaysia on a work visa. Upon arrival, they directed her to a different line where she just literally walked past immigration, thinking that it was just the practice, only to realize that the rest of her colleagues, who were already there, had had their passport and visas stamped.

Will there be an issue flying back to her home country? Or are there any precautionary steps that should be taken in this case?